# Flutter WebView loading different version of page?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web, webview

I am loading a webview in flutter using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin from pub.dev
For some urls it's loading a different (old?) version of the website.

Example url : https://dtudcefraternity.org/national-conference-on-atmnirbhar-bharat-industry-4-0-making-india-smart-and-intelligent-manufacturing-hub-and-function-of-the-forum-was-held-on-8th-october-2021-at-stein-auditorium-india-hab/

How it should look (and does look on mobile browsers like Chrome and Safari):
[Browser(desired look)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVaHW.png)

How it does look in the Flutter App:
[Flutter WebView (current look)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltXGr.png)

Most notably the letters are capital (they used to be capital in an old version of the webpage) but there are some other minor differences too.
I realise the bug here might be from the web side and not the Flutter side, I would just like to know what it is so that I can ask the Web team to handle it accordingly (I am a student and very new to all of this)
Thank you.
Code for WebView:

```
WebView(
                  initialUrl: url,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onPageFinished: (c) {
                    setState(() {
                      _isLoading = false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: Try enabling javascript or if anything needed

Comment: JavaScript is enabled, I have updated answer with code @HemanthS

Comment: For me it loads normally with the newest version, try rebuilding your app.